# CSS require Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I have required CSS stylesheets many times in many of my RubyOnRails applications, and actually i need a few things demystified.

What is the difference between:

```
//=require mystyles
```

and

```
*=require mystyles
```

Both seem to work, so what is the difference?

And is this a part of the asset pipeline or a part of SASS or just plain CSS?

Comment: I've never seen "`require`" used. To include a stylesheet like one would another script, there's the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) at-rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two examples you gave are exactly the same for stylesheets, however the `//=` syntax is the only one that works for Javascript. You also need a standard CSS comment at the start (`/*`) and a close comment (`*/`) at the end of the require block to make it ignored to anything but the asset pipeline:

```
/* ...
*= require mystyles
*= require_self
*/
```

These require directives are only part of the asset pipeline, not CSS or SASS. To include a stylesheet for CSS or SASS, you would use a `@import` rule as Blieque stated in his comment.

Check out the [manifest files and directives section of the Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) on the Ruby on Rails guide site for a more detailed explanation of the difference. There is also a warning given there that might be of interest:

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the
>   Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. Using
>   Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope,
>   making variables or mixins only available within the document they
>   were defined in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, as long as it's a valid comment line, it'll work :)