# stylesheet/css not working in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

I am new to ruby on rails and trying to develop a web application, the problem is my css is not loading. I am using a free template and trying to connect it with the back end but nothing worked. Only simple html buttons/ texts are loading .

**application.html.erb**

```
<title>InstagramApp</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "default", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "default", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <%= link_to "Instagram", root_url, class: "navbar-brand" %>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>

                    <%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %>
                </li>
                  <%- if current_user %>
                  <% else %>
                  <li>
                        <%= link_to "Logout", new_user_session_path , method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?"  %> 
                  </li>
                        <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %> 
                    <li>
                        <%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %>
                    </li>

                    <% end %>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <% flash.each do |a,b| %>
            <div class="alert alert-success"> <%= b %> </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>body{padding-top:70px;}</style>
```

And in `app/assets/stylesheets` there is *bootstrap.css* and *bootstrap.min.css* .

How do i load css in localhost?

Comment: in application.html.erb use <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>, and in application.css add line //=require bootstrap

Comment: you can also learn more about it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294823/css-require-syntax

Comment: This wont work , i tried all this

Answer (score 0):

If you have place all your css files in stylesheet folder it will call automatically .If it doesn't then do rake assets:precompile and restart your server .

Comment: error is comming :-object does not support this property or method

Answer (score 0):

If your using bootstrap elements, It will be better to install the bootstrap gem [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). Easy to install and allows you to use all bootstrap components.

install the following gems:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Change application.css to application.scss

```
app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

In your `application.scss` add

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` add

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Now you can use any bootstrap component, without needed to apply the style, this is a much better way to use bootstrap in your rails app.